# making a calculation on a timestamp array

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

It is easy to perform a calculation on a timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = 1456741175
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(dt.day)
# Week day number
print(dt.weekday())
print(dt.minute)
print(dt.second)
```

But how about if my timestamp is an array, instead of a single value. For e.g:

```
timestamp = [1456741175, 1456741176, 1456741177, ....]
```

With a loop, it takes a lot of time as my array's length is more than 3 million. So, how can I perform the same calculation on an array of timestamps using a method that is simple and fast?

Comment: There is no magic here. If you have 3M items, it means that *total_time = single_item_time * N_of_items*. Since you can't reduce the *N_of_items* value, the only way you can optimise is to make *single_item_time* smaller. And I don't really see how you can optimize these few lines **simply**.

Comment: What have you tried that takes too long? You will need to loop over all of those items if you want to convert each one. What do you need to do with the converted timestamps? Do you need them all at once, or will you process them immediately, in which case a generator might solve the problem.

Comment: Partition and distribute your data structure (the array) across multiple [subprocesses](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html). That will improve performance if 1) you have multiple cores on your host, 2) the [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) does not outweigh the benefits of your partitioning.

Comment: In MATLAB, you can directly use the array instead of the value, and you can get an array output. I need the similar in python.

Comment: Another option is to use `time.localtime(timestamp)` (or `gmtime()`) to create time `struct_time` objects. I've found this to be approx 33% faster. `struct_time` objects contain the fields that you seem to need.

Comment: give me the answer of this. how can I use the whole array instead of using each values of the array in the loop.

Comment: use map (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: please give me an example by using map, Pawel.

Comment: @yusuf: A `pandas` solution is significantly faster than others. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g.

```
map(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x).weekday(), timestamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) is *pretty* fast.

```
# timestamps.py
from time import localtime
import pandas as pd

timestamps = range(1000000)    # 1,000,000 seconds starting from Jan 1, 1970

def test_pandas():
    datetimes = pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s')
    # if you just want the week days
    week_days = datetimes.weekday

def test_time():
    week_days = [localtime(t).tm_wday for t in timestamps]
```

Compare execution times with `timeit`:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import timestamps' 'timestamps.test_time()'
10 loops, best of 3: 2.11 sec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import timestamps' 'timestamps.test_pandas()'
10 loops, best of 3: 357 msec per loop
```

Pandas is about 6 times faster than using a list comprehension, which it itself a little faster than the `map()` solution in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can be calculated parallelly using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library. It will spawn number of processes and distribute the input values to those.

You can rewrite the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from datetime import datetime

def datetime_from_timestamp(timestamp):
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    print(dt.day)

timestamps = [1456741175, 1456741176, 145674117]

pool = Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(datetime_from_timestamp, timestamps)
```

Comment: Using map you can't improve the performance it's just another loop. To improve performance you have to go for **threading** or **multiprocessing** or **distributed computing**. If it's slower in single machine then you can go for distributed solution.

Comment: I have tested, and it is faster +++++++++.